# How do I choose between $\lim_{x\to a} \frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\ $ and $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$?

Tags: calculus

How do I choose between $\lim_{x\to a} \color{red}{\frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}$ and $\lim_{x\to a} \color{blue}{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}$?

Is it when I have more than two powers? For example, can I use the former for $\ y=3+4x^2-2x^3$?

Comment: Both definitions are basically the same, just different notations. In the end you'll have to evaluate similar limits.

Comment: You need $h\to 0$ in the second limit. They are the same, when you put $x=a+h$

Comment: The second limit should be h --> 0 in order to make sense.  Notice that there is no x variable in your second expression.  When working with polynomials, I typically find the second form to be simpler to work with, but both definitions are the same, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

They are equivalent definitions: We know

$$ f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a } \frac{ f(x) - f(a) }{x-a} $$

Now, put $h = x -a $. Notice $x \to a \iff x - a \to 0 \iff h \to 0 $. Hence,

$$ f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{ f(h+a) - f(a) }{h } $$

Comment: The $x-a$ version yields a simpler proof that $(d/dx)x^n=nx^{n-1}$ than the $h$ version does, as I show in my posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$
means just
$$
\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$
because there's no $x$ in the fraction. You probably mean
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$
which is exactly the same as
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$$
The former is usually more manageable, because you don't have to collect $x-a$, but simply $h$.

If $f(x)=3+4x^2-2x^3$, then $f(a)=3+4a^2-2a^3$ and
$$
f(a+h)=3+4(a+h)^2-2(a+h)^3=3+4a^2+8ah+4h^2-2a^3-6a^2h-6ah^2-2h^3
$$
so
$$
f(a+h)-f(a)=8ah+4h^2-6a^2h-6ah^2-2h^3=h(8a+4h-6a^2-6ah-2h^2)
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}(8a+4h-6a^2-6ah-2h^2)=8a-6a^2
$$
With $(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)$ the computation is less obvious.

---

The method actually can be greatly simplified when polynomials are concerned, because of a nice property: when you expand
$$
(a+h)^n
$$
you can simply write it as
$$
a^n+na^{n-1}h+h^2P_n(a,h)
$$
where $P_n(a,h)$ is a polynomial expression in $a$ and $h$. Why is this? The case $n=1$ is obvious; then
\begin{align}
(a+h)^{n+1}&=(a+h)^n(a+h)\\
&=(a^n+na^{n-1}h+h^2P_n(a,h))(a+h)\\
&=a^{n+1}+na^{n}h+ah^2P_n(a,h)+a^nh+na^{n-1}h^2+h^3P_n(a,h)\\
&=a^{n+1}+(n+1)a^nh+h^2\bigl(aP_n(a,h)+na^{n-1}+hP_n(a,h)\bigr)
\end{align}
and we have proved the thesis, because certainly
$$
P_{n+1}=aP_n(a,h)+na^{n-1}+hP_n(a,h)
$$
is a polynomial expression in $a$ and $h$ once $P_n(a,h)$ is.

So, in the case of $f(x)=x^{20}$ we just need
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(a+h)^{20}-a^{20}}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{20}+20a^{19}h+h^2P_{20}(a,h)-a^{20}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\bigl(20a^{19}+hP_{20}(a,h)\bigr)\\
&=20a^{19}
\end{align}

You don't need the full development as it would be in the case of $x^{20}-a^{20}$.

Comment: I disagree.  The computation is simpler with the $f(x)-f(a)$ version.

Comment: @MichaelHardy And I respectfully disagree with you. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. Both of these formulas will give you the VALUE of the derivative of a function at the particular point $a$.

When we say $a$, it means we are plugging in the value $a$ into our function before we do our calculations.

Compare these to the formula $$f^{\prime}(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ this expression gives you the derivative FUNCTION.

So, the first two formulas give the same value of the derivative at the point $a$ and the formulas $f'(x)$, known as the definition of the derivative, gives the derivative function for a differentiable function.

Comment: So they both give you the same value of the derivative, and they both give you the derivative of the function.  If that's what you're trying to say, it doesn't seem all that clear that that's what you're trying to say.  And if that's _not_ what you're trying to say, then it's even more opaque.  And if your trying to say that one of them does not give you the derivative of the function (and it almost looks as if that's what you're trying to say) then you're wrong.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious from what I said, that the first two formulas give the VALUE of the derivative of the function at the point and the latter gives the derivative FUNCTION.

Comment: Then you're wrong:  They _both_ give the derivative function.

Comment: It is not wrong. It is quite clear. I am speaking of comparing the first two formulas posted by the o.p. (that tell you the VALUE of the derivative of the function at $a$) And a third that I posted (the definition of the derivative) for comparison. The Definition of the Derivative gives you the derivative FUNCTION as opposed to a value. For example if $$f(x) = x^2$$ then the derivative function is $$f^{\prime}(x) = 2x$$ But the derivative of $x^2$ for $x=2$ is $$f^{\prime}(2) = 2 *(2) =4 $$

Comment: Both versions can equally be taken to be the definition of the derivative, and some books use one and some the other (for example, Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ gives the $f(x)-f(a)$ version as the _definition_).  The part of your answer that remains vague is that you nowhere say that ONLY the one that uses $f(x+h)-f(x)$ gives you the derivative function and that the other one does NOT.  However, to say that the other one does not give you the derivative function is wrong.  My own posted answer to this present question shows just how to use the $f(x)-f(a)$ version to show.....

Comment: ....that $(d/dx)x^n=nx^{n-1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: And now I've added to my posted answer a proof that $\dfrac d{dx}\sin x=\cos x$ by using the fact that $\dfrac d{dx}\sin x=\lim\limits_{w\to x}\dfrac{\sin w - \sin x}{w-x}$ and evaluating the limit.  No knowledge of derivatives is needed in order to evaluate this limit by the method used in my answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score -2):

How does one show that $\dfrac d {dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$?  The way I first learned it was this:
\begin{align}
\frac d {dx} x^n & = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left( x^n + nx^{n-1}h + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^{n-2}h^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6x^{n-3}h^3+\cdots+h^n \right)-x^n}{h} \\[8pt]
& \text{etc.}
\end{align}
This is perfectly comprehensible, and I was amazed that it was possible to find the exact slope, but it is overkill.  Let's apply it to a concrete case:
\begin{align}
\frac d {dx} x^4 & = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(x+h)^4-x^4}h \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(x^4+4x^3h+6x^2h^2+4xh^3+h^4)-x^4}h \qquad\longleftarrow\text{overkill} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{4x^3h+6x^2h^2+4xh^3+h^4}h \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{h\to0} (4x^3+6x^2h+4xh^2+ h^3) \\[8pt]
& = 4x^3 + 0 + 0 + 0.
\end{align}
Now here it is the other way:
\begin{align}
\frac d {dx} x^4 & = \lim_{w\to x}\frac{w^4-x^4}{w-x} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{w\to x}\frac{(w-x)(w^3+w^2 x+wx^2 + x^3)}{w-x} \qquad\longleftarrow\text{not overkill} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{w\to x} (w^3+w^2x+wx^2+x^3) \\[8pt]
& = x^3+x^3+x^3+x^3.
\end{align}
The reason the first version is overkill is that it requires you to use every binomial coefficient when you actually only need the first two.

Imagine this in the case of $x^{20}$
$$
(x^{20} + 20x^{19}h + 190 x^{18}h^2 + 1140 x^{17}h^3 + 4845 x^{16}h^4 + \cdots+h^{20})-x^{20}
$$
(and then $x^{20}$ cancels and then $h$ cancels)

versus

$$
(w-x)(w^{19}+w^{18}x+w^{17}x^2+w^{16}x^3+\cdots+x^{19})
$$
(and then $w-x$ cancels).

In the first version we have all those numbers:
$$
1, 20, 190, 1140, 4845, \ldots
$$
but only the first two are really needed.  Even showing that there are some such numbers, without evaluating them, is immense overkill for this problem.

Let's apply this to show $\dfrac d{dx}\sin x = \cos x$:
\begin{align}
\frac d {dx} \sin x & = \lim_{w\to x}\frac{\sin w - \sin x}{w-x} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{w\to x}\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{w+x}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{w-x}2\right)}{w-x} \text{ (a trigonometric identity)} \\[8pt]
& = \left( \lim_{w\to x} \cos\left(\frac{w+x}2 \right)\right)\left( \lim_{w\to x} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{w-x}2\right)}{\left(\frac{w-x}2\right)} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \left( \lim_{w\to x} \cos\left(\frac{w+x}2 \right)\right)\left( \lim_{v\to0}\frac{\sin v} v \right) \\[8pt]
& = (\cos x)\cdot 1.
\end{align}
In this argument, only one basic limit, $\displaystyle\lim_{v\to0}\frac{\sin v}v=1$, is needed, whereas the more conventional argument needs two: that one and also that $\displaystyle\lim_{v\to0}\frac{1-\cos v}{v}=0$.

Comment: One can avoid actually deriving the rest of the binomial coefficients for this application. As long as you can see that *some constant* appears there, it does not effect the limit.  I agree that the second method is cleaner.

Comment: Even establishing that _some_ constant goes there is a lot of unnecessary work.  Those other constants aren't needed at all.

Comment: To avoid the symbolic "overkill" you could always write the short hand notation for the binomial expansion, e.g. $$(x+h)^4=\sum_{k=0}^4{4\choose k}x^{4-k}h^k,$$ especially for large powers.

Comment: @pbs : That doesn't avoid, or even reduce, the overkill.  You still need to show that there is such an expansion and it has all those coefficients, and that that holds not only for $n=4$ but for other values of $n$.

Comment: Could those who down-voted this explain why?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted? (+1) it is very educational answer.

Comment: @HoracioOliveira This answer presents a point of view I (and possibly others) don't agree with. For instance I believe that using prosthaphaeresis for the derivative of sine is wrong, because it needs an obscure formula rather than the addition formula. Two limits instead of one? So what? The limit $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-\cos h}{h}$ *is* a basic limit and sooner or later the students will need it. However I didn't downvote, because the answer is clear and well written; it's also helpful for deciding to choose a different strategy.

Comment: The main point of this answer is really that either of the two limits can be taken to be the definition of the derivative, and either will yield the same results. The secondary point is that in some cases, notably $(d/dx)x^n=nx^{n-1}$, one form has an advantage over the other.  The derivation of $\sin'=\cos$ is intended more to show that either approach can be used than anything else.

Comment: @egreg : You comment that sooner or later the students will need that other limit is nonsense.  A calculus course taken by a vast population of students majoring in philosophy, geography, music, pre-med, literature, etc. should acquaint students with the reasons why calculus is one of humankind's great achievements.  That goal should not be sacrificed to the goal of teaching them everything they will need if they're career path follows the instructor's.

Comment: I'm talking about majors in mathematics, computer science or engineering. I don't think I'd bother with such proofs with students majoring in other disciplines: neither the “$x-a$” nor the “$h$” approach.

Comment: @egreg : Universities encourage large numbers of other students to take calculus, and then lie to them about the subject. By restricting topics to those that somebody else will need later, they encourage the belief that doing mathematics consists of believing and obeying.

Comment: @egreg : Besides, it is unreasonable to expect to instruct more than one student in the course of your career whose career path will resemble yours.